# How would I go about making a class with a primitve array integers?

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java, but I have a good understanding of how classes work, but not Arrays. I am trying to create a PrimitiveArray class that has a single instance variable, a primitive array of Integers. Next, I am trying to create a PrimitiveArray object that has [N] random integers.

I am running into errors when I try to make the Array within the driver. The type of Array is the class (PrimitiveArray). The error is basically when I call PrimitiveArray. The IDE says incompatible types required PrimitiveArray[], found PrimitiveArray.

```
public class PrimitiveArray {
    int intArray[];

    public PrimitiveArray(int amount) {
        this.intArray = new int[amount];
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        PrimitiveArray intArray[] = new PrimitiveArray(5);
       for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
           PrimitiveArray[i] = rand.nextInt();
       }
    }
}
```

Can you please explain as thoroughly as possible what I am doing wrong, and how to correct it. Thank you.

Comment: I don't mean this as an insult, but I wouldn't call this a good understanding of how classes work. Try a visit to the [Oracle java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html), they're very in-depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't creating a new array type, you're creating a class which holds an array. Thus `PrimitiveArray intArray[]`, aka a `PrimitiveArray[]`, isn't quite what you want. It'd just be a plain `PrimitiveArray`, which already denotes something holding an array field.

```
public class PrimitiveArray {
    int[] internal; //this data should be accessed through a method, encapsulation

    public PrimitiveArray(int amount) {
        this.internal = new int[amount];
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        PrimitiveArray intArray = new PrimitiveArray(5);
        //this may do well in the constructor, which you can pass your random to
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.internal.length; i++){
            intArray.internal[i] = rand.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with `PrimitiveArray`, there is an `intArray` field which is visible to members of the same package (which is a little odd); normally you'd make that `private`. You haven't given `PrimitiveArray` a `length` field. And you need methods for accessing and changing the values within your `intArray`. Then, I believe you might find overriding `toString()` is an easy way to output the values. Something like,

```
public class PrimitiveArray {
    private int[] intArray;
    public int length;

    public PrimitiveArray(int amount) {
        this.length = amount;
        this.intArray = new int[amount];
    }

    public void set(int i, int v) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < length) {
            this.intArray[i] = v;
        }
    }

    public int get(int i) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < length) {
            return this.intArray[i];
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(intArray);
    }
}
```

Finally, in calling it; you don't want an array of `PrimitiveArray`(s), and you need to use something like the `get` and `set` methods above (since Java does not have *operator overloading*). Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    PrimitiveArray intArray = new PrimitiveArray(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        intArray.set(i, rand.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println(intArray);
}
```

P.S. as pointed out by [@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) in the comments, though I initially made it so to meet with your original code; `length` should not be a `public` field and should also be accessed through a method. Like,

```
public class PrimitiveArray {
    private int[] intArray;
    public int length() {
        return intArray.length;
    }
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length(); i++) {
```